# how do I know that I have apache static file configuration correct with mod_wsgi

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I have apache 2.2 with mod_wsgi handling /
WSGIScriptAlias / "...wsgihandler.py"

I have followed instructions to setup static file handling with AliasMatches and a matching directory configuration.

The website is working fine.

How can I determine that static content is served by Apache and not via wsgihandler.py
 working? The apache access log file doesn't help me, even when I set it to debug.
I've tried to intercept and read traffic between Firefox and the server, but that didn't enlighten me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work out what the URLs of the static files are and then comment out the WSGIScriptAlias. The URLs should still work.

Note that in general you would not use AliasMatch but just Alias. You might want to provide the appropriate parts of the Apache configuration so it can be reviewed to see whether you are doing it in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt:
load the headers_module

and in 

Header set MyHeader "Static content served"